# Creating secure .exe files in C#

Tags: c#, executable

I have heard some mutterings about C# being quite easy to "crack" and/or reverse engineer.

Is this the case and if so, how can I go about preventing this, if possible ? Or at least making it more difficult ?

Thanks, George.

Answer (score 3):

**[Obfuscate](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-us&q=obfuscators+.net&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)** your assembly.

You can refer to this [instituitional article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) to learn more about Obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

You can obfuscate your source code using for example Dotfuscator software which comes with Visual Studio. 
If you want to see reverse engineering in action - download [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), and open your exe in it. You'll be surprised :)

Answer (score 1):

You could [obfuscate](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/02/24/79236.aspx) the generated assembly.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent it is. The IL can be viewed and reverse-engineered. Some people use [obfustators](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator) to scramble all of the names in the assembly, thus making it near impossible to derive any app logic.

Comment: Ok thanks. Does this apply to other languages such as C++, VB etc too ??

Comment: Yes - all of the .NET compilers (C#, VB, C++, F#) will spit out language-agnostic IL which can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of libraries to deal with this, I think Microsoft release (or at least endorse) [Dotfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator)

Answer (score 1):

.Net code is pretty easy to view even when compiled, because all the metadata (the information about classes, methods and properties) is all contained in the executable. Basically all you need to get at the code is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Obfuscating will basically rearrange and rename everything to make tools like Reflector harder to use. There's a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699049/good-obfuscator-for-vs2010-and-net-v4-projects-with-built-in-visual-studio-integ) asking about which particular obfuscater you could use.