# Newbie Trying To Deploy Asp.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, security, visual-studio-2010, web, publish

I'm basically wondering what the best way to deploy an Asp.Net Web Site is, mostly from the point of view of security.  Right now, I'm trying to publish the website using Visual Studio 2010.  Could someone direct me to a good tutorial on how to do this securely?  For example, can it be done over an encrypted connection via Visual Studio?  Is it necessary to install any software on the server to do this?  Should I use a different program to open up an SSL (TLS) connection first, and if so, which program (does it come standard with windows)?

The server is running Windows Server 2008.  Development is on Vista.

Many thanks in advance for any direction in this matter!

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: First thing is to check with the owner of the server, as they often will provide you an FTP connection and will take care of configuring IIS.

If you want to add security, make a keyfile and sign your assemblies and consider running Dotfuscator on your dlls, the community edition is included in Visual Studio. Here is an earlier question where I've put more info on [Dotfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699049/2699220#2699220).

If you have to do the deployment yourself, here's a few things to consider.

- **XCopy** (easy)
- **MSI** (have to create a setup program, you can do this easily in Visual Studio)

There is no security advantage in deploying using Visual Studio, but you can use Visual Studio to create a small setup program. One thing you want to make sure for security is DO NOT deploy any .cs files. Prepare your files, you should compile in Release mode, make sure debug is not enabled in your config file, keep your bin and it's dll, also the aspx, asmx, ascx, svc, css, js, and config files.

- **XCopy**: Install a small FTP server, or use one your company alreayd has, this will allow you to get your files once you are logged into the target machine. You should be able to get an administrator account for the target machine, just ask the sysadmin of the domain, then log on using remote desktop, got to your ftp site, and download your files. Open IIS on the target machine, create a virtual directory and a pool. Copy your files to the location, configure your connection string to your DB if you use one, then test your website.
- **MSI**: same process as above, except the setup will create the virtual directory and pool for you.

Here is extra info on best practices from the official [ASP.Net website](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/34/deployment/).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Your answer is really detailed and helpful, so I have to mark it as correct:)  Good ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I would publish the site to your local machine and file copy the files across to your test/production environment.  As a rule we don't publish sites straight from VS to test or production.

For example you don't want to accidentally push things straight from dev into a live environment do you?

As far as the file transfer security goes you could use SFTP.

Comment: Thanks Dieter!  That's a good point about publishing a local copy before deployment.  I hadn't quite thought of how to do that.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some control on the server (e.g. to configure IIS7), you might want to look into Microsoft Web Deploy (new product just been released):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx

Haven't tried it myself, but looks quite slick and it apparently encrypts the data being copied up, so might suit you.